# Bash in mac and image magick

Tags: bash, macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a .sh in osx mac to generate icons context in app, but when i run script i get a message

```
convert: unable to open image `c.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
convert: unable to open file `c.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3917.
convert: no images defined `mipmap-mdpi/c.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

and file c.png stay in folder

```
read original
read nombre_resultante
read size


Resize () {

  if [ "$size" == "1" ]; then
    SIZE_MDPI="48x48"
    SIZE_HDPI="72x72"
    SIZE_XHDPI="96x96"
    SIZE_XXHDPI="144x144"
    SIZE_XXXHDPI="192x192"
  elif [ "$size" == "2" ]; then
    SIZE_MDPI="24x24"
    SIZE_HDPI="36x36"
    SIZE_XHDPI="48x48"
    SIZE_XXHDPI="72x72"
    SIZE_XXXHDPI="96x96"
  fi

  rm -rf mipmap-mdpi/*
  rm -rf mipmap-hdpi/*
  rm -rf mipmap-xhdpi/*
  rm -rf mipmap-xxhdpi/*
  rm -rf mipmap-xxxhdpi/*

  convert $original -resize "$SIZE_MDPI" mipmap-mdpi/$nombre_resultante
  convert $original -resize "$SIZE_HDPI" mipmap-hdpi/$nombre_resultante
  convert $original -resize "$SIZE_XHDPI" mipmap-xhdpi/$nombre_resultante
  convert $original -resize "$SIZE_XXHDPI" mipmap-xxhdpi/$nombre_resultante
  convert $original -resize "$SIZE_XXXHDPI" mipmap-xxxhdpi/$nombre_resultante
}

Resize $size
```

Comment: are you sure the file exists? you could pre-check it in bash before running the commands. And your $size argument is useless when calling `Resize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that the file `c.png` doesn't exist. I can reproduce your error message with a non-existent file:

> ```
> $ convert nonexistent.png -resize 48x48 a/b/whatever.png
> convert: unable to open image `nonexistent.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
> convert: unable to open file `nonexistent.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3913.
> convert: no images defined `a/b/whatever.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3241.
> ```

Probably you are in the wrong directory when you run the script.
`cd` to the correct directory where the file exists, and also where the sub-directories `mipmap-*dpi` exist.

You can add a check before calling the resizing function like this:

```
if [ ! -f "$original" ]; then
    echo fatal: file does not exist: $original
    exit 1
fi
```